# How do I set random elements in a 2d numpy array without looping?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array of zeros onto which I want to set some random elements to ones. First the rows are selected and then the columns, like this:

```
>>> A = np.zeros((100, 50))
>>> rows = np.random.choice(100, size = 10, replace = False)
>>> cols = np.random.randint(50, size = 10)
>>> A[rows][cols] = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: index 24 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10
```

Of course I can solve the problem with an explicit loop:

```
>>> for row in rows: A[row][np.random.randint(50)] = 1
```

But I don't want to. Can what I want to do be accomplished using numpy without explicit looping?

Comment: `A[rows,cols] = 1`

Comment: You use the same axis twice. A[rows] returns set of row, so its shape is 10,50. Then you try again to get rows of that slice.

Comment: I don't see the difference to just initiating an array with 0's and 1's. Wouldn't `np.random.randint(0, 2, (100, 50))` also solve your problem?

Comment: @user8408080 OP wants only 10 ones

Comment: But then `randint` won't help either, because it could potentially yield the same pair of numbers twice

Comment: I oversimplified so I edited the question. Thank you @splash58 `A[rows, cols]` was what I was looking for.

Comment: @user8408080 it seems unlikely that both number will be the same but possible although

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to randomly sample in 2D matrix in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44447179/how-to-randomly-sample-in-2d-matrix-in-numpy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide all indexes in one set of brackets, like so
`A[rows,cols] = 1`